# Can't Install flutter android licenses

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am not able to accept the flutter android licenses
after I run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I get the error as

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Rathi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
```

Also I have installed the flutter plugins in Android Studio still error is showing up that the plugins are not installed

Answer (score 1):

First try to Execute command prompt as administrator.
Otherwise, try : (your android_sdk folder exact path)\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses